question about parse liquidiity
When we use the getParsedAccountInfo method to parse a pool ID, we usually use LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4 to decode the results. In the final parsed data, what does each field mean?
need your help，please。
thank you，everyone！
const parsedAccInfo = await connection.getParsedAccountInfo(new PublicKey(poolid));
const parsed = LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.decode(parsedAccInfo?.value.data)
if(!parsed) return
let pooldata =  {
status:parsed.status.toNumber(),
nonce:parsed.nonce.toNumber(),
maxOrder:parsed.maxOrder.toNumber(),
baseDecimal:parsed.baseDecimal.toNumber(),
quoteDecimal:parsed.quoteDecimal.toNumber(),
state:parsed.state.toNumber(),
minSize:parsed.minSize.toNumber(),
tradeFeeNumerator:parsed.tradeFeeNumerator.toNumber(),
tradeFeeDenominator:parsed.tradeFeeDenominator.toNumber(),
pnlNumerator:parsed.pnlNumerator.toNumber(),
pnlDenominator:parsed.pnlDenominator.toNumber(),
swapFeeNumerator:parsed.swapFeeNumerator.toNumber(),
swapFeeDenominator:parsed.swapFeeDenominator.toNumber(),
quoteNeedTakePnl:parsed.quoteNeedTakePnl.toNumber(),
quoteTotalPnl:parsed.quoteTotalPnl.toNumber(),
baseTotalPnl:parsed.baseTotalPnl.toNumber(),
quoteTotalDeposited:parsed.quoteTotalDeposited.toNumber(),
baseTotalDeposited:parsed.baseTotalDeposited.toNumber(),
baseVault:parsed.baseVault.toBase58(),
quoteVault:parsed.quoteVault.toBase58(),
baseMint:parsed.baseMint.toBase58(),
quoteMint:parsed.quoteMint.toBase58(),
lpMint:parsed.lpMint.toBase58(),
openOrders:parsed.openOrders.toBase58(),
marketId:parsed.marketId.toBase58(),
marketProgramId:parsed.marketProgramId.toBase58(),
targetOrders:parsed.targetOrders.toBase58(),
withdrawQueue:parsed.withdrawQueue.toBase58(),
lpVault:parsed.lpVault.toBase58(),
owner:parsed.owner.toBase58(),
lpReserve:parsed.lpReserve.toNumber(),
padding:parsed.padding.toString()

}
I can parse these data, but what next? What does each field mean? Which fields are more important? How can I leverage their value? I don't know how to proceed with the next steps
If you can help me, I would be very grateful.
